# Can Matrices be passed as arguments in Octave?

Tags: octave

I am implementing the non-vectorized form of the cost function in octave. This is the code from my `.m` file

```matlab
function computeCost(X, y, theta)
sigma=0;
theta0 = 0;
m = length(y);

for i = 1:m
sigma = sigma+ theta*X(i)-y(i);
end;

J = ((sigma)^2)/2*m;

end;
```

My octave code is:

```matlab
>> X= [1,1; 1,2; 1,3; 1,4;];
>> y= [2;4;6;8];
>> J = computeCost(X, y, 0.5);
```

where `X` and `y` are matrices. However, I am getting this output on my CLI Window:

```matlab
Error: computeCost(X, y, 0.5) undefined near line 1, column 5
```

I've checked my code, there is no apparent issue. Is it because Octave does not accept matrices as parameters for its functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is clearly YES: The name MATLAB is an abbreviation of *Matrix laboratory*. Octave and Matlab are specially designed to facilitate working with matrices.

The problem in your code is: Your function definition is incomplete. You have not defined J as return value. The error message you see is a bit missleading because it should state column 10 as place of the error. When you change the first line of your code to

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
```

It will work as expected and output the value `648`.